# share a file using php

Tags: php, email, session

my problem is am not able send a downladable  link to mail ,
actually i have selected two variable  which i have get the values of (userID ,userPic) below the so now am not able to send the link to mail

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['useremail'])) {


    $uploadID =  $_GET['uploadID'];
    $filename =    $_GET['userPic'];
    $memberID =$_SESSION['memberID'];
    $email   =     $_SESSION['email'];
    $mail  =     $_POST['useremail'];

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO share(uploadID,useremail,userPic,memberID) VALUES(:uploadID, :useremail,:userPic, :memberID)');
                $stmt->bindParam(':uploadID',$uploadID);
                $stmt->bindParam(':useremail',$mail);
                $stmt->bindParam(':userPic',$filename);
                $stmt->bindParam(':memberID',$memberID);

                if($stmt->execute())
                {
                    $successMSG = "succesfully sended mail ..." ;
                    header("location:user.php"); 
                }   


    > Blockquote
    $url = "<p>

 <a href='http://www.adroitsws.com/data_transfer/download.php?filename=<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>'>http://www.adroitsws.com/data_transfer/download.php?filename=<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?></a></p>"

     $email_from =$email;

        $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

        function died($error) {

            // your error code can go here

            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

            echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

            echo $error."<br /><br />";

            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

            die();

        }
            if(!isset($_POST['useremail'])  ) {   

            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

        }

        $email_to = $_POST['useremail']; // required

        $error_message = "";

        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

      if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_to)) {

        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

      }


        function clean_string($string) {

          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

        }

        $email_message .= "mail: ".clean_string($email_to)."\n";

    // create email headers

    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email_to."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail( $email_to, $email_subject,$url, $email_message, $headers);  

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check following links which shows how to send mail with attachment in php.

1. [From stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)
2. [From sanwebe](https://www.sanwebe.com/2011/01/send-php-mail-with-attachment)
3. [From tutdepot](http://www.tutdepot.com/php-e-mail-attachment-script/)

Also Find out that in your code there is error. Please replace your $URL by below code and check.

```
$url = "<p> <a href=http://www.adroitsws.com/data_transfer/download.php?filename=".$row['userPic'].">"
            . "http://www.adroitsws.com/data_transfer/download.php?filename=".$row['userPic']."</a></p>";
```

Comment: actually file is  downloadable and download  link should be sent to mail  and the file should be downloaded when the link is click : similar as DROPBOX.    aM TRYING  to send the download  link  but am not able to send it

Comment: Even though you provide links to the answer to this question, it would be better if you take the relevant code of it and use it in your answer.

Comment: @rahulpallela: I checked your code again and find that there is error in your code. May you please replace your $URL by this  $url = "<p> <a href=http://www.adroitsws.com/data_transfer/download.php?filename=".$row['userPic'].">"
                . "http://www.adroitsws.com/data_transfer/download.php?filename=".$row['userPic']."</a></p>";